# Could not load type 'GatewayDeduplication' from assembly 'NServiceBus.Core

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I installed RavenDB and then in the configuration I did:

```
public static void ConfigurePersistence(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {

            var defaultStore = new DocumentStore
            {
                Url = "http://localhost:8085",
                DefaultDatabase = "MyTestb"
            }
             .RegisterListener(new UniqueConstraintsStoreListener())
            .Initialize();

            configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>()
                .DoNotSetupDatabasePermissions()
                .SetDefaultDocumentStore(defaultStore);
        }
```

When I run the project then I am seeing below error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load t
ype 'GatewayDeduplication' from assembly 'NServiceBus.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c'.
   at NServiceBus.Persistence.RavenDBPersistence..ctor()


 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal
& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at NServiceBus.Utils.Reflection.ExtensionMethods.Construct[T](Type type) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Utils\Reflecti
on\ExtensionMethods.cs:line 22
   at NServiceBus.Persistence.PersistenceStartup.Run(Configure config) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Persistence\Persist
enceStartup.cs:line 32
   at NServiceBus.Configure.<Initialize>b__7(IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized t) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\C
onfigure.cs:line 114
   at NServiceBus.Configure.<>c__DisplayClasse`1.<ActivateAndInvoke>b__d(Type t) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure
.cs:line 180
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
   at NServiceBus.Configure.ForAllTypes[T](IList`1 types, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:li
ne 138
   at NServiceBus.Configure.ActivateAndInvoke[T](IList`1 types, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure
.cs:line 182
   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:line 116
   at NServiceBus.Bus.Create(BusConfiguration configuration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Bus.cs:line 21
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1 moreConfiguration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\
GenericHost.cs:line 121
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 58
```

I am not able to find why this is coming. What is

> GatewayDeduplication I never tried to load this DLL I dont care this but still Nservicebus is trying to load this dll and failing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried to do    `configuration.DisableFeature(typeof(GatewayMessage)); `Still there is no luck.

Comment: I am stuck with this error not able to proceed. Even though I installed Nservicebus.Gateway still it is showing the same error.

Comment: In this line only I get the error for GatewayDeduplication     `Bus = 
                NServiceBus
                .Bus
                .Create(configuration)
                .Start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the NServiceBus package to the latest (5.2.0) and this should solve the issue

Comment: Thanks Sean ! I removed all Nservicebus dependent nuget packages then installed all of them latest with NserviceBus 5.2.0 it fixed my issue.